# using cancellation link after event start date?

Tags: civievent, online-registration

It seems that Civi does not allow people to use the self-service cancellation after the event start. We have some multi-day and longer-term events that it would be very helpful for them to still be able to self-cancel. 
Questions:
* Is there setting to let Civi permit cancellations after the event start?

- If not...would the event online registration setting "cancellation or transfer time limit (hours)" - could that be made negative somehow (i.e. until 1d after event start)?

Just a user, not a developer here, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

By chance I also recently discovered this limitation, and [opened a ticket](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/event/issues/34) for it.

I wrote the code to add this feature, but it requires a change to the CiviCRM schema, so I don't recommend patching yourself unless you know what you're doing.  I [wrote a patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16615) to clean up checking whether a participant can self-update.  Once that's approved, I'll submit a patch to allow negative values for the "hours until cancellation" field.

Answer (score 0):

I think(but not sure) if you append is_backoffice=1 to the self-service cancellation url it should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the idea-> I tried it-> error is: "24_isbackoffice=1) is not of the type Positive" In case it matters, this is a Wordpress site. id=24 are the last digits of the cancellation URL.

Comment: You will need to add &is_backoffice=1

Comment: If you need to add arguments to url or link it should be separated by &

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! OK, the box that says "Sorry registration for this event cannot be cancelled..." goes away, but the box that says "Registration is closed for this event" is still up, and it won't let me cancel. Any ideas how to let registrants use their self-service cancellation links after the event has begun? Thanks again.